# ping webservice through ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a web service example http://blahblah:5555/blahblahWS,
when can confirm that the Web services application was deployed by entering the Web service endpoint URL in a browser, then viewing an informative page. The information page contains the following information:
{http://webservice.pli.tc.wssvt.ibm.com}RetireWebServices 
Hello! This is an Axis2 Web service!

When we see this, we can confirm that WebService is fine, so how can i confirm it through jquery $.ajax call?

I wanted to create a page which shows all the services and their statuses

Answer (score 3):

Use Status codes settings of the jQuery.ajax method, look at this example below.
This example confirms if WebService1 is available, just a hint...

```
           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "WebService1.asmx/GetItems",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                statusCode: {
                    404: function () {     //404 is for not found
                        alert('service not found');
                    },
                   302 : function () {     //302 is for found
                        alert('service found');
                    },  
                  500 : function () {     //Internal server error
                        alert('Internal error');
                    }  
                }
            });
```

To know more about HTML codes go to this site : http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

God bless.

Comment: You're missing status 200 for ok.

Comment: You can add several status codes, I just added three as an example.

Comment: Yeah I know, just thought that 200 was one of the important ones, which is why I pointed it out. The +1 is from me.